FastAPI - how to handle generic exceptions in websocket endpoints
I would like to learn what is the recommended way of handling exceptions in FastAPI application for websocket endpoints.
I tried:
app.add_exception_handler(Exception, handle_generic_exception)

It catches Exception, but it doesn't catch, e.g. ValueError.
I also tried to use @app.middleware("http") but it doesn't seem to work with websockets.
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()


app.add_exception_handler(AppException, handle_disconnect)

@app.middleware("http")
async def generic_exception_middleware(request: Request | WebSocket, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception as exc:
        send_something_to_client()
        print("some exception")


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket):
    raise ValueError("foo")

Would anyone of you know what is the proper way of handling generic exceptions for websocket endpoints?
EDIT 2024-05-28:
I finally added the decorator for handling exceptions for my websocket endpoints. But if there is any more elegant solution, please let me know!
def handle_exceptions(func):
    """Decorator for handling exceptions."""

    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(websocket: WebSocket):
        try:
            await func(websocket)
        except WebSocketDisconnect as exc:
            raise exc
        except AppError as exc:
            await app_error_handler(websocket, exc)
        except Exception as exc:  # pylint: disable=broad-exception-caught
            await generic_exception_handler(websocket, exc)

    return wrapper

[...]

@handle_exceptions
async def accept_api_v1(websocket: WebSocket):
    """Handle api v1 request."""
    await websocket.accept()
    do_things()

@app.websocket("/api/v1")
async def ws_api(websocket: WebSocket):
    """API v1 endpoint"""
    await accept_api_v1(websocket)


I'd try doing a ``try except Exception" in the websocket endpoint and raise that as an exception type that I can catch.

I finally ended up with something like this. I have more websocket endpoints, so I added decorator to have one piece of code with it, but I thought that there might be more elegant solution.

I am also looking for better solutions. Currently i add ASGIMiddleware to fastapi app, it catches both websocket and http. If you only want to hanlde websocket, you can use scope['type'] == 'websocket' to filter requests.
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket


class ASGIMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        try:
            await self.app(scope, receive, send)
        except:
            do_something()


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(ASGIMiddleware)


@app.websocket('/sample')
async def sample(socket: WebSocket):
    raise ValueError('ERROR')

